# Power transformer circuit using H-bridge doesn't work as expected

Tags: transformer, h-bridge, mosfet-driver, step-up, astable

I am trying to step up my AA battery's voltage (which is 8 volts in total) using an ignition coil (which is rated for 12 volts input.)

To drive the coil I am using an H-bridge at a frequency of 50 kHz but the coil's output is only about 5 V.

I tried building my own custom transformer using toroid ferrite core but the output is only around 20 V even though the turns ratio is 5:50 (around 80 volts output expected.)

Here's the circuit:

[image: Astable multivibrator drives the H bridge mosfets]

Why is it not stepping up the voltage as it should?

UPDATE: Problem completely solved
It was all due to my bad oscilloscope which is rated for 800Vpp but after some tests it was not able to detect voltages above ~20V.

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope? If so, please show us the voltage across the bridge. I suspect it is low due to the inability of the AA batteries to drive enough current without voltage droop.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy , thank you for your help , I do have an oscilloscope but sometimes it shows me that there is no voltage (it is so low - around 356mv) and sometimes it shows me there is but it drops to 2 volts as you suspected , in a few daysI'll try buying an appropriate battery and dump those AAs and I'll update you if the problem was solved , thanks again , I really appreciate it !

Comment: Are you sure about the signal routing ABCD? Check the conduction paths, A and C should be swapped on the mosfet side.

Comment: @Jens , thanks for the response , as I understand the Astable Multivibrator part of the circuit - A and B conducts at the same time , and C and D conducts at the same time , so if we are gonna swap A and C at the H bridge side (mosfets' gates) it wouldn't function as H bridge circuit should because it would just pull down each side and it won't be changing the direction of current at the load (because we want to create AC here) etc... correct me if I am wrong

Comment: first step: Are you sure that your astable is working? NPN transistors mean that the emitter goes to the ground ...

Comment: @Antonio51 Thanks for the response , yes , the Astable connected correctly and works as it should .

Comment: What transistors are you using? Also which Ferrite core and how many turns on the primary?

Comment: @BruceAbbott , thanks for the response ,
Transistor : TIP122 .
Mosfet : IRF540N , FQP27P06 .
Ferrite material : PC40 .
Primary turns : I've tried it all - 5 turns , 10 turns , 20 turns , the more turns in the primary - the less voltage my oscilloscope recognize , don't know why .
btw I am aware of the inductive kick of the primary of the coil and that's why I've connected some P channel mosfets in series which each other so they can handle it , the circuit works and the waveform is as expected but voltage is low .

Comment: _"I've connected some P channel mosfets in series which each other so they can handle it"_ - there is no reason to do that.  _" A and B conducts at the same time , and C and D conducts at the same time"_ - not in the schematic you posted. Please show us the actual circuit, drawn properly.

Comment: _"I do have an oscilloscope"_ Good. Please post oscillograms of Vgs for each MOSFET.

Comment: I've updated the question , please see , thanks

Comment: Your edit is a 112 word long sentence. Please improve the readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED : the mosfet has an inner system protection of overvoltage because of it's inner protection diode , so by connecting an external flyback diode it solved the problem and the mosfet is no more limiting the primary's voltage .

Comment: Is "FQP27P06" an HITFET ?

Comment: it is said in the datasheet to be a QFET

Comment: Right. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QFET , but don't understand why this "protection overvoltage scheme" can be "shorted" by an external diode?

Comment: @Antonio51 I really don't know why it solves my problem , I would like to know too , I have no idea but it seems to me that it has to do with the external diode bypassing some kind of limitation built in the mosfet , I assume it's the body diode , if there is an inner circuitry in the mosfet itself - it may be the cause , but again - I have no idea nor the tools to check it out unfortunately .

Comment: Ok. Is it the same behavior if there is an extra capacitor (say some 100uF) in series with the primary of XFMR1 (without the external diodes)? Should ask the manufacturer of these MOSFETs ...

Comment: @Antonio51 Yes , same behavior , checked with a 10uF capacitor because that's the largest capacitor I got , even if I change those MOSFETs with a transistor or other types of MOSFETs I still get the same behavior , even tried now 600V rated MOSFETs and still nothing changes so I might be wrong about "bypassing the inner diode" because a 600V MOSFETs should not have any problems with the inductive kick of this circuit .

Comment: @Antonio51 so I might be wrong about "bypassing the inner diode" because a 600V MOSFET should not have any problems with the inductive kick of this circuit , so now I know I am wrong and it must be something with my circuit , maybe a bad power supply - but I've tried using Lithium batteries which are capable of 20A and same result , frustrated...maybe something with my breadboard...

Comment: No worries. It should be probably good to make a new "version" of the "board". NB: it is somewhat difficult when the load (double/triple resonant) is the same as I have simulated. So, good luck and very much "patienza" (Italian). Keep us informed. NB: the voltage on my MOSFETS does not reach such voltages ... I will check.

Answer (score 4):

Now to your H-bridge. I assume this is the MOSFET configuration you wanted to draw, everything else with 2 P-FET in the upper half and 2 N-FET in the lower half would make no sense anyway.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxAENY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to explain 4 static cases:

1. PHASE_A is 0 V and PHASE_C is 0 V. M1 off, M2 off, M3 on, M4 on, no transformer current.
2. PHASE_A is 5 V and PHASE_C is 0 V. M1 on, M2 off, M3 off, M4 on, transformer current.
3. PHASE_A is 5 V and PHASE_C is 5 V. M1 on, M2 on, M3 off, M4 off, no transformer current.
4. PHASE_A is 0 V and PHASE_C is 5 V. M1 off, M2 on, M3 on, M4 off, reverse transformer current.

A dynamic analysis would show transformer currents in each case, but this is not my point here. When a phase input changes state, there is a short dangerous moment where both FETs in a leg conduct. This is called cross conduction and should be avoided. So this circuit is only useful if the sum of the threshold voltages of both FET is close to the supply voltage. This is not the case in your circuit, so I expect excessive current peaks drawn from the battery.

You can improve this by splitting up the gates and adding 4 voltage divider resistors per side, as shown here. Your 330 ohm resistors may be a wrong implemented approach in this direction. If you want to use an 8 V supply something to prohibit cross conduction should be done.

This is not a good solution at all, I only wanted to explain a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help , I know what you're talking about and I agree with you but the thing is - no matter how I switch voltage to the coil - the voltage is just low at the output , I've never seen more than 40 Vpp on my custom made transformer and even less than that on the ignition coil , I've tried H bridge as I showed here , I've tried LC Circuit with mosfets switching it to ground , and no matter what's the design of the switching circuit the output is still very low .

Comment: @lidorov19: Ignition coil is designed for flyback converter topology, this is a forward converter. There are big differences in possible voltage and current transfer ratios.

Answer (score 2):

Astable with NPN BJT should be working as this :

[image]

Now adjust values to your needs.  It should be the choice of R1, R2 .. R3, R4, C1 .. C2.

As you have tried, you know now that it is not a simple task using transformers.
Here is a sample of what can be used for that goal (400 V peak).
Some conditions must be met to make this work ... and need time.
All specifications for the devices are not checked. Only simulation. Vc is Vc2.

[image]

For other conditions, I got 3 kV peak. NB: Efficiency is very low < 10 %.

For 80 Vpeak, RL = 350 Ohm.

Comment: Thanks for the response , yes , the Astable Multivibrator part of my circuit works as you described , at the first time running the circuit it didn't work correctly because of the hfe of the transistors so I had to bump up the resistance of R3 and R4 and then it worked perfectly , so yes my Astable works OK .

Comment: Now, think a little about only the "correct" driving of the H-bridge. In the simplest form of the driver of the MOSFETs, there are "2" states. What are they? And how do you drive the 4 MOSFETs? What are the levels of voltages needed? Tip: two voltages only are needed. To simplify ... think only at one side (left) of the H-bridge.

Comment: The 2 states are high and low voltages , here the N mosfets get around 7 volts and the P mosfets get around 4 volts , they both need no more than 4Vgs to turn on completely (saturation) and I am aware that the P mosfet may be not fully into saturation but it shouldn't result in this really low voltage at the output of the coil , and as I've said in other comments - I've tried one more circuit design which was a simple ground switching LC circuit but got the same results , so the H bridge is not the problem here , it must be something else but I have no idea what it is .

Answer (score 0):

Problem completely solved - bad oscilloscope , voltage was perfect and the oscilloscope wasn't able to read it .